# Flutter. Changing screen to landscape, it automatically turns back to portrait

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

On the main menu screen, I call `forcePortrait()` which is:

```
static Future forcePortrait() async {
await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
]);


 }
```

Then ... I'm calling the below from inside the main menu screen:

`Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenBoard()));`

In the Board screen, I call `UScreen.forceLandscape()`as below

```
class ScreenBoard extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _ScreenBoardState createState() => _ScreenBoardState();
}

class _ScreenBoardState extends State<ScreenBoard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UScreen.forceLandscape();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.redBckgnd,
      body: Container(

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the `forceLandscape() method`

```
static void forceLandscape() async {
await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
  }
```

My problem is that it does move to the new screen and **IT DOES** rotate the screen to landscape, but after a couple of seconds, it moves it back to portrait. Why is that ?! I can't figure it out!

**EDIT**

I've noticed that if I don't call `forcePortrait()` on the menu screen, the board screen doesn't switch back to portrait. But still can't figure out why!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Wow. I think I figured it out. The `forcePortrait` and `forceLandscape` methods were called from inside the `build()` method. Apparently after pushing to the Board screen, the Main Menu screen did another run through the `build()` method, and it did this after the Board sceren did, thus `forcePortrait` was called after `forceLandscape`.

Solution was to move them to the `initState` method which was called only once. I now run into another problem that when clicking back and returning to the menu screen, it won't recall `initState` and the screen remains in portrait, but that's a job for later.

Anyway, interesting mechanism, I did not know that happened.

Disclaimer: I'm only 2 weeks into Flutter